# Panning Law amplitude interpolation with Octave

Tags: matlab, audio, plot, octave, audio-panning

I am working on a project that uses the tangent law to localize a phantom source in the typical stereo setup (two loudspeakers at 60º angle).
Since the tangent law shows a relation between the angle of the phantom image and the gain of the loudspeakers, my aim is to plot the amplitude response in dB of one loudspeaker at the different angles of the phantom source, here is the code that works fine with the source positioning:

```
%-----stereo panning------%
%variables:
Fs = 44100;
theta = 25;       %virtual source
phi = 30;         %loudspeaker
g(1) = 1;         %L gain
g(2) = -(tan(theta)-tan(phi)) / (tan(theta)+tan(phi));
%sum of gains has to be normalized
g = g/sqrt(sum(g.^2));
signal=mod([1:20000]',200)/200;          %signal
loudsp_sig=[signal*g(1) signal*g(2)];    %panning
soundsc(loudsp_sig,Fs);                  %play audio
```

I tried creating a theta vector and tried plotting (theta, 20*log(g(2)), also using table but either it gives me an error or plots only one point, I'm clearly missing something here.

Comment: `g(2)` can only be one value. It is a single index. You cannot expect a single index to store anything but a scalar and hence you have errors.

Comment: I think you also intented to use `g = g./sqrt(...)` rather than `g = g/sqrt(...)` to divide element-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g(2)` can only be one value. It is a single index. A vector cannot be stored in one memory location. If `theta` is a vector then the resulting expression

```
   tan θ – tan ϕ 
– ——————————————
   tan θ + tan ϕ
```

should also be a vector calculated for each element in `theta` and therefore [element-wise division](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html) will be needed (as [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54315176/panning-law-amplitude-interpolation-with-octave#comment95469137_54315176) by [Wolfie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3978545/)).

So, use the same number of indices as required by `theta` to store all the gains `g`:

```
g(2:numel(theta)+1) = -(tan(theta)-tan(phi)) ./ (tan(theta)+tan(phi));
```

---

Also note that the [`tan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tan.html) function calculates the tangent of argument in radians. If you want to put the angle in degrees, use [`tand`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tand.html) i.e.

```
g(2:numel(theta)+1) = -(tand(theta)-tand(phi)) ./ (tand(theta)+tand(phi));
```

Comment: You are using the same y-coordinate (calculated for just `g(2)`) for all the points. What else result do you expect other than getting the same value on y-axis?. `g(2)` is one point. It is not a vector. You are meant to do: `plot(theta, 20*log(g(2:end)), '*');`